# Limit ImageWMS request size

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

Is there any built-in way of limiting the request width/height of ImageWMS sources and have the map just scale the image up to fill the extent? I'm building an application that includes a bunch of WMS providers that don't support resolutions higher than 2048.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 - Stretch

Custom loader
If the image is larger than 2048px, store originalWidth and originalHeight and request image with min(2048, original[Width|Height]).
Draw requested image into a canvas with size (originalWidth, originalHeight)
Set canvas data as src for Image
Solution 2 - Tile

Use TileWMS with a tile grid of 2048px sized tiles
Recreate source and tile grid everytime projection changes